# Getting a Bad Request (400) when I try to GET data from the Twitter API using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

My code looks like this:

```
(function() {
    var Twitter = {
        init: function() {
            this.url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=football';
            this.fetch();
        },

        fetch: function() {
            $.getJSON(this.url, function(data) {
                var tweets = $.map(data.results, function(tweet) {
                    return {
                        id: tweet.id,
                    };
                });
                console.log(tweets);
            });
        }
    };

    Twitter.init();
})();
```

I am just trying to get the tweets with the word football in them, and display it on my page. However, I get this error in my console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

What gives? Also, if I directly go to that url, I get the following error in JSON:

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

What am I missing exactly? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that now API v1.1 requires that the request must be authenticated, check Authentication & Authorization documentation for more details on how to do it. Also note that the search results at twitter.com may return historical results while the Search API usually only serves tweets from the past week.

You need to be authenticated in order to call the API. Read more in the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

Comment: I understand, however, most solutions I could find used PHP as a back-end to store the API key and secret. Is there any way I can do that within my Javascript code? As I am only building a simple app for learning JQuery. Thanks.

Comment: There are examples out there that do not use PHP. Twitter offers a list of libraries here https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries. Codeacademy has a tutorial that uses Ruby as the backend. Only "pure javascript" way would likely require some node.js.